# sum rows of column based on a repeating range of values in another with pandas groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with several thousand rows that looks something like:

```
Index Chan Pick
1      1   0.001
2      2   0.001
3      3   0.001
4      4   0.001
5      1   0.003
6      2   0.003
7      3   0.003
8      1   0.006
9      2   0.006
10     1   0.002
11     2   0.002
12     3   0.002
13     4   0.002
14     5   0.002
15     6   0.002
```

The channel `Chan` column has values that can range from 1 to 24 (sometimes there may be all 24 values, sometimes there may only be 2 values or 6 values, etc. as shown above).
The values in the `Pick` column will usually be the same for each group of channel values.

I need the average value in the `Pick` column from a common channel block (i.e. the first block will avg to 0.001...the second block avgs to 0.003, because the `Pick` values are all the same, but sometimes they may not be).

I know I need to use something similar to:

```
df.groupby('Chan')['Pick'].mean()
```

but I don't know how to implement the fact that `Chan` can be from 1 to 24 and then the pattern starts over (i.e. the `Chan` column can be 1 to 4, or 1 to 22, or 1 to 17, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A channel block essentially starts when the `Chan` value is exactly 1. We have to exploit this property to accomplish the task.

Let `channel_id` be a variable identifying each block with a unique progressive identifier. We can define it as follows:

```
channel_id = (df["Chan"] == 1).cumsum()
```

where `(df["Chan"] == 1)` creates a mask with a `True` where each block starts, then `cumsum` does the job propagating the identifier over the block and increasing it each time a new block starts.

Now we have just to `group by` according to this identifier and take the mean value of the `Pick` column:

```
df.groupby(channel_id)["Pick"].mean()
```

You can do everything in one line without supplementary variables.

Comment: This works nicely unless the "Chan" column doesn't start at 1. Meaning there wasn't a pick at Channel 1 or 2 or 3 etc. Any thoughts on how implement that change?

Comment: What if the first channel block has only one entry with Chan 1 and the second channel block starts from Chan 2 because it misses Chan 1? How could you recognize that they are two distinct blocks? In general it is easy to recognize if an increasing sequence stops and starts a new one, but in the counter example we cannot recognize that there are two blocks.

Comment: If you can ignore the problem I mentioned in the previous comment, you can used the following code to recognize the channel block which recognizes the increasing sub-sequences: `channel_id = np.concatenate([[True], df["Chan"].values[1:] <= df["Chan"].values[:-1]]).cumsum()`.